# jQuery .each() does not update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if a set of radio buttons has been selected. However, it seems that it does not update if a radio is selected after the fact.

The code:

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
    var addr_chkd = 0;
    $('input:radio[name="address"]').each(function() { 
        if (!$(this).attr('checked'))
            addr_chkd++
    });
});

if (addr_chkd)
    // do something
```

When the button is clicked and nothing is selected, the code works great. However, when a radio button is selected and the button is clicked, `addr_chkd` still returns a value greater than zero.

**[UPDATE]**

The issue is that I'm checking for `addr_chkd` greater than zero. I should be checking if `addr_chkd` is equal to the length of the radio buttons. I made a slight modification to @PPvG's answer and it did the trick.

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
    var radios = $('input:radio[name="address"]');
    var num_unchecked = radios.filter(':not(:checked)').length;
    if (num_unchecked === radios.length) {
        alert('please select a button');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would it not be greater than 0?  Only one radio button will be check correct?  That means that the counter will increase for each unchecked radio button.  What is it that you want the code to do?

Comment: I want to make sure that at least one radio button is checked. My logic may be faulty (and the reason this isn't working), but if addr_chkd > 0 then no buttons have been checked.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
    var addr_chkd = 0;
    $('input:radio:[name="address"]').each(function() { 
        if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
            addr_chkd++
    });
});
```

or you can simply do it as

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {    
    var addr_chkd = $('input:radio[name="address"]:not(:checked)').length
}
```

since at a time only one radio button can be checked so you can also do as

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {    
        var addr_chkd = $('input:radio[name="address"]').length - 1;
}
```

fiddle example for all the above : http://jsfiddle.net/pdm2F/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but I can interpret `addr_chkd` in two ways.

If the "addr" stands for "adder", and you want to **count** the number of unchecked radio buttons, use this:

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
    var radios = $('input:radio[name="address"]');
    var num_unchecked = radios.filter(':not(:checked)').length;
    if (num_unchecked) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

If, on the other hand, "addr" means "address", and you want the **index** of the selected radio button, use this:

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
    var radios  = $('input:radio[name="address"]');
    var checked = radios.filter(':not(:checked)').get(0);
    if (checked.length > 0) {
        var index_checked = radios.index(checked);
        // do something
    }
});
```

Note that in both cases, I moved the `if` clause inside the `click` handler. In your example, it was outside the `click` handler, which means it would be executed only once, and even before the button was clicked.

Comment: I want to count the number of uncheked radio buttons. And thanks for pointing out that the if is outside the click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a much easy way:

```
var addr_chkd = $('input:radio[name="address"]:checked').length;
```

Or if you mean not checked:

```
var addr_chkd = $('input:radio[name="address"]').not(':checked').length;
```

But for the radio input, you may do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).attr()` instead of this.